# Find Max in Sequence from Input - Problem with negative integers

Tags: java

I'm quite new on Java and I'm facing an issue in this excercise:
Write a method, findMax(), that repeatedly reads in integers until a 0 integer is read and keeps track of the largest integer that has been read. findMax() then returns the largest number entered.

My problem is that my code (below) is working when the input contains at least one positive integer but it is not working when the input contains only negative integers:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMaxInSeq {
    public static int max() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSoFar = 0;
        int currValue;

        do {
            currValue = scanner.nextInt();

             if (currValue > maxSoFar) {
                maxSoFar = currValue;
            }
        }
            while (currValue != 0);

            return maxSoFar;}


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Test your code here!\n");

        FindMaxInSeq test = new FindMaxInSeq();
        System.out.println(test.max());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any negative number is smaller than your initial value for `maxSoFar`. The simplest way to fix this is to make that initial value smaller. For example, you could use the smallest possible `int` value by [using `Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE).

Comment: If 0 should be the end input, when your max is at 0 it should mean you are reading the first number and you can just overwrite it

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I've tried already but when the sequence is only of integers as an output I got "0" instead of the higher value.

Comment: @losfastidios: please [edit] your question with the code you tried, and provide a sample of which input you provide and what output you get then.

Comment: Hi your while condition you should replace with <while (scanner.hasNextInt())
  scanner.nextInt();>       this because your negative integer input 0 (zero) is the big number so you are getting zero as output .

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I've solved it also with your hint and the hint coming from Randommm. Quick question as I'm new here: where can I put the code that solved the question? Can I mark the question as "resolved" or something similar? Thanks for the support and the patience!

Answer (score 0):

When your default maxSoFar value 0 and you input only negative integers, they can't be max. Also do {} while in last iteretion set 0 to max value.
Try this:

```
public static int max() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxSoFar = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    int currValue = scanner.nextInt();

    while (currValue != 0) {
        if (currValue > maxSoFar) {
            maxSoFar = currValue;
        }

        currValue = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    
    return maxSoFar == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? currValue : maxSoFar;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution that solves my issue:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindMaxInSeq {
public static int max() {

    // Put your code here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int maxSoFar = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int currValue;

    do {
        currValue = scanner.nextInt();

        if (currValue == 0);

         else if (currValue > maxSoFar) {
            maxSoFar = currValue;
        }
    }
        while (currValue != 0);

        return maxSoFar;
   }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Test your code here!\n");

    // Get a result of your code
    FindMaxInSeq test = new FindMaxInSeq();
    System.out.println(test.max());
}
}
```